# Ckeditor scrolls to top in Microsoft Edge

Tags: scroll, ckeditor, microsoft-edge

I have a problem in Microsoft Edge in Ckeditor. Try the [Ckeditor Demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo), scroll down a little and then click all to the left, at beginning of a line. The editor scrolls to top.

Others experienced this? Something to do about it? Or is this "just" a bug?

Comment: I am having the same issue: http://g.recordit.co/zIvBqQXZWl.gif

Answer (score 0):

Use [CKEditor bug tracker](http://dev.ckeditor.com) for reporting issues/bugs. Issue that you're describing sounds a lot like https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13152, so you could reopen it.

Comment: @Marek Lewandowski  I updated this ticket: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/14556  Any way you can bump up the priority on that ticket. Pretty much makes CKEditor not usable on Windows 10 machines.